# JavaScript Error en Formularios

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

a la hora de crear un programa básico para que me de el resultado dentro de una caja de texto, se está complicando y no sé a qué es debido; he mirado incluso en posibles errores en la consola, y  aparentemente no existen. Aquí dejo el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Ejemplo de JavaScript</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function pagar(){

      var socio = parseInt(form1.name);
      var entradas = parseInt(form1.ent);

      switch(socio){

        case 1: if(entradas>5){
            parseInt(form1.total) = socio * entradas;
        }
        break;

        case 2: if(entradas>=10){
            parseInt(document.form1.total) = socio * entradas;
        }
        break;
      }
    }

  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <form name="form1">

    <p>Tipo de Miembro: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <p>Numero de Entradas:  <input type="text" name="ent"></p>
    <input type="text" name="total">
    <input type="button" onClick="pagar()" value="incrementar">
    <button name="atras">Deshacer</button>

  </form>






</body>

</html>
```

El problema que me encuentro, es que a la hora de ejecutarlo no aparece ningún resultado sobre la caja de texto creada. Por mi suposición el problema debe estar principalmente en el switch, ya que cuando clicamos en el botón y entra en la función, si que funciona al tener una alerta. Pero actualmente estoy sin mayor conocimiento de lo que está pasando con mi programa. Gracias por ayudar.

Comment: Yo veo errores en la consola: los `if` que hay en cada case tienen una llave `{` de apertura pero no de cierre, con lo que el código da error de compilación

Comment: He cambiado un poco el codigo que había subido ya que tenía cierta incoherencia. La cosa es que quiero que el resultado final se visualice en el text box de total. Pero no coge el valor de socio.

Answer (score 1):

hay un poco de lío en tu código, desde una llave no cerrada en el primer case como intentar acceder al formulario vía nombre. Te recomiendo usar los id para acceder a los formularios o sus inputs, te he modificado el código usando el id en el formulario y accediendo a los inputs mediante elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements  el resultado lo puedes ver con un console log en vez de un document.write, (inspeccionar elemento>consola). También en el botón de deshacer te he puesto que sea type button para que el botón de manera natural no haga submit y puedas llamar a una función en caso de que quieras darle utilidad a ese botón.
También he quitado el parseFloat del total ya que estabas haciendo un parsefloat de algo y luego igualandolo a una operación (te daría este error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597667/referenceerror-invalid-left-hand-side-in-assignment) , para estos casos es mejor que el total lo iguales y luego realices el parseFloat pero en este caso no es necesario aplicarlo
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

```js
   function pagar(){
         var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario").elements;
         
            var socio = parseInt(formulario["name"].value);
            var entradas = parseInt(formulario["ent"].value);
            var total = formulario["total"].value;

          //  alert(formulario["name"].value);
            switch(socio){

                case 1: if(entradas>5){
                         total = socio * entradas;
                       // document.write(total);
                        console.log(total);
                        }
                        
                        break;
                case 2: if(entradas>=10){
                         total = entradas * 0.95;
                        //document.write(total);
                        console.log(total);
                        } 
                        break;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
        <title>Ejemplo de JavaScript</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">


</head>

<body>

    <form id="formulario" name="form1">
        
        <p>Tipo de Miembro: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
        <p>Numero de Entradas:  <input type="text" name="ent"></p>
        <input type="text" name="total">
        <input type="button" onClick="pagar()" value="incrementar">
        <button type="button" name="atras">Deshacer</button>
        
    </form>
        





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: He copiado el codigo tal y como lo pones, pero sigue sin mostrarme el resultado en total.

Comment: Si quieres mostrarlo, descomenta los document.write, si quieres mostrarlo en alguna caja concreta, haz un etiqueta de html que vaya a tener ese texto, lo recoges con un document.getElementById y luego con .innerHTML le das el valor, por ejemplo: document.getElementById("resultdiv").innerHTML = total;

Answer (score 0):

claro que no va a pasar nada, en ningun momento actualizar el total

```js
    let name = document.getElementsByName("name")[0]
    let ent = document.getElementsByName("ent")[0]
    let total = document.getElementsByName("total")[0]
    
    function pagar(){

      var socio = parseInt(name.value);
      var entradas = parseInt(ent.value);
      console.log({entradas, socio})
      
      switch(socio){

        case 1: if(entradas>5){
            total.value = socio * entradas;
        }
        break;

        case 2: if(entradas>=10){
            total.value = socio * entradas;
        }
        break;
        
        default:
            total.value = socio * entradas;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
      <title>Ejemplo de JavaScript</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body>

  <form name="form1">

    <p>Tipo de Miembro: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <p>Numero de Entradas:  <input type="text" name="ent"></p>
    <input type="text" name="total">
    <input type="button" onClick="pagar()" value="incrementar">
    <button name="atras">Deshacer</button>

  </form>






</body>

</html>
```